# Remove all the div elements except a div which comes first after h1 tag in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

My requirement is to keep the first div element which comes after every heading h1  and delete all other div elements

```
   <html>
    <head> ...</head>
   <body> 
     <div id="content">
       <div> <span> data.....</span> </div>

      <h1 id="head1">Customers </h1>
      <div class="abc"> 
          <table> <tr><td> Customer data</td>.  </tr></table>
       </div>
      <div class="abc"> extra div </div>
      <div class="abc"> one more extra div </div>

      <h1 id="head2">Orders</h1>
      <div class="abc"> 
         <table> 
            <tr><td> Orders data</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
     <div class="abc">extra div </div>
     <div class="abc">one more extra div </div>

      <h1 id="head3">Expenditures </h1>
       <div class="abc"> an extra div</div>
       <div class="abc"> one more extra div </div>

    <h1 id="head4"> Depositors </h1>
    <div class="abc"> an extra div </div>
    <div class="abc">an one more extra div </div>

     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How to achieve this ?

Mycode: (modified)

```
 Elements contElements = document.select("content");
 for(Element e :  contElements) {
    if(e.tagName().equals("h1") &&  (!e.attr("id").equals("hd1") &&    !e.attr("id").equals("hd2")){
        //remove h1 element with other id and all  div's after this h1 element
    }
    else {
          //keep h1 elemwnt and the first div comes after h1 and   remove all other divs comes after this h1
    }
```

How can I fit the below suggested answers inside the above code snippet

My Expected output:

```
  <html>
   <head>  </head>
   <body>
    <div ID="content">
   <div> <span> data.....</span> </div>

    <h1 id="head1">Customers </h1>
    <div class="abc"> 
          <table> <tr><td> Customer data</td>.  </tr></table>
     </div>

      <h1 id="head2">Orders</h1>
      <div class="abc"> 
         <table> 
            <tr><td> Orders data</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>

        </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Below suggested answers not working as expected.. Updated the question

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the divs more than the first one using the pseudo selector `:gt(n):`

So your selector would look like

```
Elements elements = document.select("h1 ~ div:gt(1)");
```

Comment: it will find <div> elements preceded by <h1> whose sibling index is greater than 1. I don't think this is OP want. Maybe he update his question ...

Comment: @Alice: yes..I updated my complete question and code logic written by me...I just want the missing logic to get the expected output.

Comment: Raised as a separate question.can u please help me on this

Comment: @LazyGuy I think you got an answer, to remove specific h1

Answer (score 1):

The error with your approach is that it selects all the div elements following a h1. see [here](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

You can use `Elements elements = document.select("#content div:not(h1+div)");`

This will remove all the divs inside #content, which are not preceded by a h1 element.

Comment: @LazyGuy did you check this answer, I think it is work. append elements .remove();

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the previous siblings name is h1 and if its not then remove it?

```
Elements elements = document.select("h1 ~ div");

for (Element element : elements) {
    if (!element.previousSibling().nodeName().equals("h1")) {
        element.remove();
    }
}
```